# How do I adjust the window and keyboard size?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have installed Ubuntu Touch on my HTC Desire, it is working well but the size of my keyboard is too big!!

How can I adjust this?

Comment: Uhm, the HTC Desire has very limited support and not even a single tester is listed at [the device page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/bravo). Maybe you just can't expect too much at this point in time.

Comment: Old question but still applicable: on my new Aquaris M10 the keyboard is just ridiculously big...